# Manipulating Dates with dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have longitudinal, geocoded address data and the length of time at each geocode. I then have a series of variables (I'm just calling them x here) that give characteristics of each geoid location. Below here is just two cases but I have thousands.

```
id<-c(1,1,1,7,7,7,7)
geoid<-c(53,45,45,16,18,42)
start<-c("1/1/2004","10/31/2004","1/1/2005","1/1/2005","6/1/2007","7/2/2007")
end<-c("10/30/2004","12/31/2004","12/31/2007","5/31/2007","7/1/2007","12/31/2007")
x<-c(.5,.7,.7,.3,.4,.6)
dat<-data.frame(id,geoid,x,start,end)
dat$start<-as.Date(dat$start,format='%m/%d/%Y')
dat$end<-as.Date(dat$end,format='%m/%d/%Y')
dat

  id geoid   x      start        end
   1    53 0.5 2004-01-01 2004-10-30
   1    45 0.7 2004-10-31 2004-12-31
   1    45 0.7 2005-01-01 2007-12-31
   7    16 0.3 2005-01-01 2007-05-31
   7    18 0.4 2007-06-01 2007-08-01
   7    42 0.6 2007-08-02 2007-12-31
```

I need to end up with a single value for each year (2004, 2005, 2006, 2007) and for each case (1, 7) that is weighted by the length of time at each address. So case 1 moves from geoid 53 to 45 in 2004 and case 7 moves from geoid 16 to 18 to 42 in 2007. So I calculate the percent of the year at each geoid (and eventually I will multiply that by x and take the mean for each year to get a weighted average). Cases staying put for a whole year will get a weight of 1.

```
#calculate the percentage of year at each address for id 1
(as.Date("10/31/2004",format='%m/%d/%Y')-as.Date("1/1/2004",format='%m/%d/%Y'))/365.25
Time difference of 0.8323066
(as.Date("12/31/2004",format='%m/%d/%Y')-as.Date("10/31/2004",format='%m/%d/%Y'))/365.25
Time difference of 0.1670089

#calculate the percentage of year at each address for id 7
(as.Date("05/31/2007",format='%m/%d/%Y')-as.Date("1/1/2007",format='%m/%d/%Y'))/365.25
Time difference of 0.4106776
(as.Date("07/01/2007",format='%m/%d/%Y')-as.Date("06/01/2007",format='%m/%d/%Y'))/365.25
Time difference of 0.08213552
(as.Date("12/31/2007",format='%m/%d/%Y')-as.Date("07/02/2007",format='%m/%d/%Y'))/365.25
Time difference of 0.4982888
```

I can do this by brute force by looking at each year individually, calculating the percent of the year spent at that address.  Then I would multiply each weight by the x values and take the mean for that year - that will not be reasonably possible to do with thousands of cases. Any ideas of how to address this more efficiently would be much appreciated. Seems like it might be doable with dplyr slice but I'm stalled out at the moment. The key is separating out each year.

Answer (score 4):

As eipi10 mentioned, some of your data spans more than a year. It also looks inconsistent with the data you used in your time difference calculations, which are all within the same year.

Assuming that your start and end dates would actually be in the same year, you can do something like the following:

```
foo <- dat %>%
         mutate(start_year=year(dat$start), 
                end_year=year(dat$end), 
                same_year=(start_year==end_year), 
                year_frac=as.numeric(dat$end - dat$start)/365.25,
                wtd_x = year_frac * x)
```

This gives you:

```
id geoid   x      start        end start_year end_year same_year  year_frac      wtd_x
1  1    53 0.5 2004-01-01 2004-10-31       2004     2004      TRUE 0.83230664 0.41615332
2  1    45 0.7 2004-10-31 2004-12-31       2004     2004      TRUE 0.16700890 0.11690623
3  1    45 0.7 2005-01-01 2007-12-31       2005     2007     FALSE 2.99520876 2.09664613
4  7    16 0.3 2007-01-01 2007-05-31       2007     2007      TRUE 0.41067762 0.12320329
5  7    18 0.4 2007-06-01 2007-07-01       2007     2007      TRUE 0.08213552 0.03285421
6  7    42 0.6 2007-07-02 2007-12-31       2007     2007      TRUE 0.49828884 0.29897331
```

You can then group and summarise the data using:

```
bar <- foo %>%
  group_by(start_year, id) %>%
 summarise(sum(wtd_x))
```

to give you the answer:

```
start_year    id     sum(wtd_x)
   (dbl) (dbl)         (dfft)
1       2004     1 0.5330595 days
2       2005     1 2.0966461 days
3       2007     7 0.4550308 days
```

Comment: That's actually the exact question I am trying to get at. I have data overlapping years but need a measure for each individual year. That's the part I can't figure out how to extrapolate from my data

Comment: Do you care about columns id, geoid and x being of the same values when you split them into individual years?

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this will get you started. I wasn't sure how you wanted to deal with cases where the period from `start` to `end` spans more than one year or crosses calendar years.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(fractionOfYear = as.numeric(end - start)/365.25)
```

> ```
>   id geoid   x      start        end fractionOfYear
> 1  1    53 0.5 2004-01-01 2004-10-30     0.82956879
> 2  1    45 0.7 2004-10-31 2004-12-31     0.16700890
> 3  1    45 0.7 2005-01-01 2007-12-31     2.99520876
> 4  7    16 0.3 2005-01-01 2007-05-31     2.40930869
> 5  7    18 0.4 2007-06-01 2007-07-01     0.08213552
> 6  7    42 0.6 2007-07-02 2007-12-31     0.49828884
> ```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find some local help that led us to a simple function. We're still stuck on how to use apply with dates but this overall handles it.

```
#made up sample address data
id<-c(1,1,1,7,7,7)
geoid<-c(53,45,45,16,18,42)
start<-c("1/31/2004","10/31/2004","1/1/2005","1/1/2005","6/1/2007","7/2/2007")
end<-c("10/30/2004","12/31/2004","12/31/2007","5/31/2007","7/1/2007","12/31/2007")

dat <- data.frame(id,geoid,start,end)

#format addresses
dat$start<-as.Date(dat$start,format='%m/%d/%Y')
dat$end<-as.Date(dat$end,format='%m/%d/%Y')

#function to create proportion of time at each address
prop_time <- function(drange, year){

  start <- drange[[1]]; end <- drange[[2]]

  #start year and end year
  syear <- as.numeric(format(start,'%Y'))
  eyear <- as.numeric(format(end,'%Y'))

  #select only those dates that are within the same year
  if(syear<=year & year<=eyear){

    byear <- as.Date(paste("1/1", sep="/", year), format='%m/%d/%Y')
    eyear <- as.Date(paste("12/31", sep="/", year), format='%m/%d/%Y')

    astart <- max(byear, start)
    aend <- min(eyear, end)

    prop <- as.numeric((aend - astart))/as.numeric((eyear - byear))

  } else prop <- 0 #if no proportion within same year calculated then gets 0

  prop

}

#a second function to apply prop_time to multiple cases
prop_apply <- function(dat_times, year){

  out <- NULL

  for(i in 1:dim(dat_times)[1]){
    out <- rbind(out,prop_time(dat_times[i,], year))
  }

  out

}


#create new data frame to populate years
dat <- data.frame(dat, y2004=0, y2005=0, y2006=0, y2007=0)
dat_times <- dat[,c("start", "end")]

#run prop_apply in a loop across cases and selected years
for(j in 2004:2007){

  newdate <- paste("y", j, sep="")
  dat[,newdate] <- prop_apply(dat_times, j)

}
```

Comment: Growing an object in a loop is a bad idea in R.

Comment: what other strategies would you suggest in this instance?

Comment: I haven't read your code carefully enough to know why you think `rbind` in a loop is useful here, so I don't know the best way out of it. Since you let `prop` take a value of zero, I guess your function is scalar-valued, in which case `mapply` might work for you. The usual reference is the short chapter 2 of this book http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf which may be helpful.